# Concatenate Rows using FOR XML PATH() from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

Apologies if there was an answer in here, but I cannot find it...Can you concatenate rows from multiple tables using FOR XML PATH. Let me explain....

I have the following 4 tables:

"BusinessSupport" which has reference to the other 3 tables

"Application", "BusinessProcess" and "OrgaUnit" (contains organizational info such as Service Line and Geography)

```
SELECT  a.NAME AS [App Name],            

        STUFF((SELECT ',' + bp.NAME as [text()] 
        FROM BUSINESSPROCESS bp 
        LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on  bp.REFSTR=bs.XOBJECT   
        WHERE bs.OBJECT=a.REFSTR FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [Business Process]    ,

        STUFF((SELECT ',' + org.NAME as [text()] 
        FROM ORGAUNIT org 
        LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on org.REFSTR=bs.YOBJECT  
        WHERE bs.OBJECT=a.REFSTR FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [Service Lines]   

 FROM APPLICATION a
```

This gives me table results such as

### **AppName**; **Business Process**; **Service Lines**

app1; process1, process2, process 3; SL1, SL2, SL3

app2; process1, process 2; SL1, SL4, SL4

app3; process4, process 2; SL3, SL5, SL6

However, I now have a new dimension I have been asked to report from.
Table 5 "Relations" which has a reference to Business Support and Orgaunit.

I would like to have something like

### **AppName**; **Business Process**; **Service Lines**; **Geography**

app1; process1, process2, process 3; SL1, SL2, SL3; Geography1, Geography2

app2; process1, process 2; SL1, SL4, SL4; Geography1, Geography3

app3; process4, process 2; SL3, SL5, SL6; Geography3, Geography4, Geography5

I have tried the following but do not get any results returned:

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + org2.name as [text()] 
FROM ORGAUNIT org2 
LEFT JOIN RELATIONS rel ON rel.TOREF=org2.name 
LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on bs.REFSTR=rel.FROMREF  
        WHERE bs.OBJECT=a.REFSTR FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [Geog]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the `SELECT` inside your `STUFF` actually returns records?  You should get that query working first.

Comment: Yep query is fine.
If I return A Geog ID as opposed to Geog name it all works fine.  But it does not have that extra JOIN to get the GEOG name

   STUFF((SELECT ',' + rel.TOREF as [text()] 
   FROM RELATIONS rel 
   LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on bs.REFSTR=rel.FROMREF
   WHERE bs.OBJECT=a.REFSTR FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [Geog ID]

Comment: Please update your answer with the query you used to test it.

Answer (score -1):

If any of your columns returned when using `FOR XML` to concatenate values return a `NULL,` then the entire concatenated string will become `NULL`, since "some string" + `NULL` is always `NULL` is SQL Server.  If it is possible for `org2.name` to be `NULL` in your example, then wrap an `ISNULL` around the concatenated results, and replace with an empty string.

```
STUFF((SELECT ISNULL(',' + org2.name, '') as [text()] 
FROM ORGAUNIT org2 
LEFT JOIN RELATIONS rel ON rel.TOREF=org2.name 
LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on bs.REFSTR=rel.FROMREF  
        WHERE bs.OBJECT=a.REFSTR FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [Geog]
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic, however, the use of ISNull does not work when I adjust the code :(

Even changing the empty string for a random string value still gives me a NULL value?

Comment: add `a.REFSTR` to your main query result set, and then for one of the results that returns a NULL for the Geography, try this query as see what results you get: SELECT org2.name as [text()] 
FROM ORGAUNIT org2 
LEFT JOIN RELATIONS rel ON rel.TOREF=org2.name 
LEFT JOIN BUSINESSSUPPORT bs on bs.REFSTR=rel.FROMREF  
        WHERE bs.OBJECT= {PutValue of a.refstr here};   If this returns 0 records, then there is an issue with your subquery having incorrect joins to get back to the Geography name.